# Help finding values in a Telerik Radgrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

I've tried to find the answer, but am not having any luck and am wasting to much time trying to figure it out.  Using RadGrid from Telerik, latest version of their Ajax Controls, I've added a Select to each row, and can't figure out how to get the value of the selected row.  Prefer to get the value of the ID column (from ID field in my database) or other specific columns.  C# or VB example will work, VB preferred.

Thanks so much!

Comment: How about some code? And surely you could have come up with a better title?

Comment: Hi John, you are right, I tried to clarify the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked Telerik's own [documentation](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/selecting/defaultcs.aspx) on the grid and select events, its pretty broad.

Comment: I did review the samples and couldn't find an answer, but have not read the docs.  I will do that, thank you.